# Gerar componentes HTML com PHP e estes atribuírem características do javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu criei um formulário que possui um painel e nesse painel tem um `input` de data com um jquery `datepicker`. Caso possui dados inseridos no banco, o meu PHP cria mais linhas neste painel (através do `ajax`) com outros `input` para inserir data, porém esses novos `input` não estão habilitando a possibilidade de escolher a data com o `datepicker`.

Acredito que seja pela ordem do processamento do javascript e do PHP na aplicação.

Como posso fazer esse novos input também atribuir o meu `datepicker`?

Obs.: os novos input também estão definidos com `class="data"`

**datepicker**

```
$('.data').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    prevText: 'Anterior',
    maxDate: new Date,
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(1) Linhas geradas pelo meu PHP quando encontra dados no banco

(2) Input com `class="data"` que não pega as característica do jquery `datepicker`.

(3) Input que já carrega quando solicito a página

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar resolver este problema usando a função "ajaxSuccess" da jQuery, esta função recebe como parâmetro uma função anônima que é executada todas as vezes que uma requisição ajax é concluída com sucesso. Esta é um evento do Ajax.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $('.data').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior',
        maxDate: new Date,
    });
});
```

Veja a documentação oficial [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) desta API.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você executa o `$('.data').datepicker({...})` pela primeira vez, o jQuery DatePicker cria instâncias do para todos os elementos .data disponíveis no DOM nesse exato momento.

Quando você cria novos componentes com Ajax o DatePicker não tem como saber que esses elementos foram criados e instanciar eles automaticamente.

Para resolver esse problema você deve, logo assim que você cria um input de data novo (preferencialmente com id único), instanciar o DatePicker novamente apenas para esse elemento.